# Lifnei 'Iver and your maybe-Jewish co-worker

Tags: halacha, gentiles, safek, lifnei-iver

I work in an office in which someone working down the hall is disabled. She has a Jewish sounding last name and talks to me about her family's practices in regard to being members of a Reform temple and keeping certain Jewish traditions like going to Miami for Passover (we've had this conversation tongue in cheek, but it impressed upon me that she has experience in Jewish practice).

Yesterday she made a comment that led me to strongly question whether she is, in fact, Halachically Jewish.

Until now I've been very mindful of avoiding situations in which I have to aid her with certain things that might constitute Lifnei 'Iver or Mesayea' issues (causing someone to sin or helping someone sin if they would have sinned anyway). If, however, I have a doubt that she is actually Jewish according to Halachah, do I need to worry about these things?

Comment: Incidentally, I don't see this as a classic CYLOR case, because I'm curious about the parameters of the laws that pertain to the case, not to my case in particular. I'm careful about this regardless. I also don't think it's too localized, but if others disagree they should feel free to edit it.

Comment: What exactly does her disability have to do with the question?

Comment: @l' The Mesayea' is much more pronounced, although I don't know that it necessarily rises to Lifnei 'Iver, as she could get someone else to help her.

Comment: @SethJ What exactly are you doing that might be a problem / not doing because you think it's a problem?  I would need to know exactly what's (not) happening to figure out if it's an issue.

Comment: @Will, see my [second example here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/15338/5). But it could easily have been a request to help her put it in the microwave and turn it on. Or it could have been a request to help her with not only treif, but Hametz on Pesah. How serious and how directly involved is part of the question. I am looking for parameters of when I need to say 'no' (if ever, since I'm not sure she's Jewish) and when I can say yes.

Comment: @SethJ okay.  Also, what was the comment she made?  "Oh, my mother's family is all Catholic.  She converted so she could marrry my dad"  I would have no problem helping her get her treif lunch from her bag, if the statement was of that nature.

Answer (score 1):

The [gemara in Avodah Zarah](http://dafyomi.co.il/azarah/insites/az-dt-006.htm) speaks of selling animals to a non-Jew.  Perhaps that non-Jew will then sacrifice this animal to his false god(s), and then the Jew who sold it to him would be guilty of lifnei iver.

However - if the non-Jew already has other animals, he will be able to do his sin, even if the Jew doesn't help.  Therefore, most views would say that the Jew may sell an animal to this non-Jew.

Using this logic, we could say the following:  If other people in the office would be willing to help this woman retrieve her treif lunch, then your refusal to do it won't stop her from eating it.  Furthermore, you'll look like a jerk for refusing, possibly causing a Chillul Hashem.

So be a mentsch and help her get her lunch.

(Chametz on Pesach might be different.  You don't want to have anything to do with Chametz on Pesach.  Even holding it might possibly constitute momentary "ownership".  In that case, I would explain that we don't go anywhere near Chametz this week, and find someone else to help her.)

Comment: I was gonna +1 until I saw the hametz part. Is hametz bipesach assur binegia the same way the etz hadDa'at was?

Comment: @l' theoretically, the diabled woman is "giving" her chametz lunch to a Jew to heat up as he sees fit.  Safek he owns the chametz at that point (it's definitely b'reshuso, and possibly, shelo).  Safek d'oraisa l'chumra, ESPECIALLY on an issur kares.  Where did I use the word negia, or touch??

Comment: "we don't go anywhere near Chametz..."

Comment: @l' that's the only the phrase I would use to explain to a non-frum Jew why I wouldn't feel comfortable taking possession of her chametz lunch.  You don't start going into details of kinyan and bal yirah / bal yimatze with a non-frum Jew.  She's an acquaintance, not a chevrusa.

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with being vague or not giving details, but I think that teaching ANYONE a **wrong** Halacha can be dangerous.

Comment: @l' I agree.  In this case, no one is teaching anything.  It's a statement, using a vernacular, in the same way that "I don't go anywhere near trans-fats" doesn't mean that he won't walk into a supermarket with margarine on the shelf.  You are really overthinking this, IMHO.

Comment: @Vram et al. - What about Tehillim 50:16, where it says that the wicked should not speak Torah?

Answer (score -1):

if it's a safek and not a vadei then since lifnei iver is min hatorah you should probably go l'chumra.

Comment: But Mesayea' is MiDeRabanan.